# Bad AJAX response, return a document in web service

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services, web-config

I have a simple web service I debbug this and have a correct answer, the code is:

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public String GetUserId()
        {
            var windowsUserDomain = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var windowsUser = windowsUserDomain.Split('\\')[1];
            IUser user = Zamba.Core.UserBusiness.GetUserByname(windowsUser);

            //this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            //JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //return jsonSerialiser.Serialize(jsonList);
        return           Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
         }
```

When I open this  WS in Chrome I have this code:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"Password":"","Crdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Lmoddate":"2014-04-16T00:00:00","Expirationtime":0,"AddressBook":"","Expiredate":"20/07/2005","Nombres":"Dl","Apellidos":"Sri","puesto":"CLAIMS","telefono":"53","firma":"","Picture":"\\\\server2008\\Volumenes\\inDanil.jpg","ConnectionId":0,"WFLic":false,"eMail":{"Type":1,"Servidor":"","Base":"","Mail":"mauso@arc.com.ar","UserName":"mroc.com.ar","ProveedorSMTP":"smtp.gmail.com","Puerto":57,"Password":""},"Groups":[{"IsFull":false,"IsLoaded":false,"State":0,"Type":1,"Description":"","Users":[],"CreateDate":"","PictureId1":0,"Name":"* CLAIMS","ID":2145}],"PictureId1":0,"Type":0,"Description":"Marsh S.A.","State":1,"IsFull":false,"IsLoaded":false,"MailConfigLoaded":false,"Name":"sta","ID":258}
</string>
```

But when I call this WS in JS with AJAX in this mode:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           async: false,
  url: "Services/UsersInfo.asmx/GetUserId",
           success: function (d) {
               thisUserId = d.User;
           }
       });
```

d = a document in HTML, not a JSON response, I put in my web.config this code:

```
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"
                 verb="*" path="*.asmx"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

But every time this return a document and not a JSON response, I cant do "d.data" or $.JSON(d) because d is a document.

How I can configure my WS, AJAX call or Web Config? Thanks

Comment: You can include `dataType: "xml"` in yout ajax call...

Comment: d is a document if I put this: d.toString()
"[object XMLDocument]" but if I try with this $(d).children()[0].innerHTML
I have that I need

Comment: I try in AJAX Call with dataType: 'json', but dont work, if I put dataType: "xml", I have the same response, but I need a JSON response and not XML

Comment: You should do some tweaks in your method: `[WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]`, and your web.config: ` <webServices>
        <protocols>
              <add name="HttpSoap"/> 
              <add name="HttpPost"/>
              <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>`, inside of: `<system.web>`

Comment: Thanks Hackerman, I had  <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/> in my web config I add only <add name="HttpSoap"/> in correct place , I replace [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] to         [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] but I have the same error